# Do we have to update everytime using 'sudo apt-get update'command whenever we install anything?

Tags: apt

Whenever I am installing anything through the terminal, the provided code includes `sudo apt-get update` (to update the local repository catalog), but do we have to run the command **each** time we install something? Does the catalog really get updated so quickly??

This is a different question because I am asking whether I have to use the command before every install.  I am not asking what it means since I know what it means, but I don't understand the necessity of updating it every single time.

Comment: not necessarily for every install from terminal. when you  add a PPA to install an app,  you have to run the command.

Comment: Thanks for duplicating the questions..:(..I described why the question was different..

Comment: ok let it go..actually i did give the reason why the question was different.Ok it doesn't matter now..Thankx for the help bdw..:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally it is enough to update the repository once a day.
But as the updates are pushed irregularly to the Ubuntu repositories,
it is recommended to update them every time before installing new packages.
In case that you add a PPA to the software repositories, updating them is mandantory.

Comment: yeah yeah i have clicked on the tick mark..:P

Comment: @RahulSingh : Thank you - enjoy ubuntu experience ! :)

Comment: hahaa..thanx bro..yeah it's a new experience..may it go wonderful for me..:)